# spamassassin rdns reversedns

Tags: email, phpmailer, php, spamassassin, reverse-dns

Spamassasin gives the following flag on my emails:

*

> 0.8 RDNS_NONE              Delivered to internal network by a host with no rDNS
>
> "This test checks to see if there is a reverse DNS entry
>   for the last untrusted relay. Note that this may be done by
>   interpreting information in the relevant Received header - if reverse
>   DNS checks are not performed by the first trusted relay, or if they
>   are not recorded in the Received header, this test will be triggered
>   (regardless of the actual rDNS status)."

*

The only ip I can see on my emails are 94.143.11.2 -> which you can reverse dns to trophymanager.com. Google and hotmail have no problems with this - but Spamassassin gives it a flag - what am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

not sure about spamassassin, but many mail filters / MTAs (postfix for example) only accept the rDNS entry if it's [Forward-confirmed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS). In your case, the forward confirmation does not work:

```
dig -x 94.143.11.2 +short
man01.trophymanager.com.
```

but man01.trophymanager.com does not have an A record.

Create an DNS record :

```
man01.trophymanager.com A 94.143.11.2
```

and Spamassassin probably won't complain anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The OP asks about this issue, but the other answers don't address that:

```
-0.8 RDNS_NONE Delivered to internal network by a host with no rDNS
```

This is caused by reverse lookups of 127.0.0.1 returning localhost, commonly caused by redirecting mail in-and-out-of localhost for spam/virus filtering (like through amavis).  It will create headers like this with rDNS showing incorrectly for as localhost for 127.0.0.1:

```
Received: from smtp.example.com (**localhost** [127.0.0.1])
    by smtp.example.com (Postfix) with ESMTPA id A5F13FEF
    for <example@example.com>; Wed, 26 May 2021 17:07:02 -0700 (PDT)
```

Note that I added *'s around **localhost** above to highlight the issue.  By updating /etc/hosts file and placing your hostname *before* the word `localhost` it will be be placed correctly in your logs:

So you want this:

```
~]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   smtp.example.com localhost localhost.localdomain 
::1         smtp.example.com localhost localhost.localdomain
```

not this:

```
~]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain smtp.example.com
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain smtp.example.com
```

and definitely not this:

```
~]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain
```

... or you can configure rDNS for 127.0.0.1 but that seems silly...just what hostname should a centralized rDNS server respond with?  Indeed, it can't ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting account comes with an IP address, you might be able to change this within the dashboard of your hosting account, or open a ticket with your host if you're not sure.

That solved my "SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch" error on https://mxtoolbox.com

However, mxtoolbox.com still complains "Reverse DNS is not a valid Hostname" the explanation from them is:

> Your Reverse DNS Record (PTR) is not a valid host name. According to
>   email sending best practices, a PTR Record should be a valid host
>   name. If the PTR Record is not a valid hostname, there is a likelihood
>   that you will experience email delivery issues with anti-spam
>   services.

I looked up my registrar -- Namecheap says:

> A PTR (pointer) record maps an IP address to the domain name. It’s
>   often called a "reverse DNS entry" because it converts an IP address
>   to a name.
>
> PTR records are mostly used as a security and anti-spam measure, to
>   verify that a mail server address is allowed to send an email to a
>   particular hostname. The reverse DNS entry checks if a server name is
>   indeed associated with an IP address from where the connection was
>   initiated.
>
> In order to set up a reverse DNS entry that will connect an IP address
>   to your domain (e.g., 127.0.0.1 should be mapped to yourdomain.com),
>   you will need to **contact your IP address provider** to create a PTR
>   record for the IP address.

It's possible I just need to wait a day, because when I updated the reverse DNS with my host there was a message saying "please wait 6-12 hours." If I remember, I'll come back and write an update.

Comment: You can't do rDNS for 127.0.0.1!  The issue is internal addresses, not external ones. Well, that is perhaps silly NameCheap documentation.